# 2 Apaches rodando Mac

Tags: php, linux, apache, osx

Estou perdido na configuração de meu ambiente de desenvolvimento local.

Tenho 2 Apaches rodando em minha maquina e gostaria de somente um, também quero deixar rodando o PHP 7.

estes são os dois locais:

> /usr/sbin/apachectl
>
> /opt/local/apache2

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Faz a desinstalação dos dois e instala utilizando [homebrew](http://brew.sh/index_pt-br.html), tanto o PHP quanto o Apache/Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Solução:

Tinha um rodando nativamente e outro através da instalação via mac ports, desinstalei o do macports.

Para o PHP 7 no OSX 10.11 somente via https://php-osx.liip.ch/